# How to add <font> with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
FM_log(3,"rp_insertTable() called");

 var farmTable = dom.cn("table");

 var ftableBody = dom.cn("tbody");

 var i;

 var maximize = GM_getValue("Maximize_" + suffixGlobal, 0);

 farmTable.className = "FMtbg";

 farmTable.id = "farmMachineTable";

 farmTable.setAttribute('cellpadding', 2);

 farmTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', 1);

 farmTable.style.marginBotton = "12px";
```

how can I add  to that table, I mean, edit the HTML in the middle of that table and add "< font >" ??? (ps: how can I add < > code here without it being interpreted as code?)

Comment: Please clarify the question - are you talking about adding an element to the DOM?
Please read the FAQ about the markup.

Comment: You have to intend every code by four spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the font name via javascript, set the `.style.fontFamily` attribute. For the size it's `.style.fontSize`

PS: Never ever use `<font>` - it's deprecated and a bad practice.